# Flexbox - Two separate flex container columns: Items don't line up on the same row line

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a main flex container with two flex containers inside - one on the left and one on the right (both have 50% width ). They are set to `flex-flow:row wrap`.
Both have their own flex items with varying height.

I don't want the rows of the columns to be at independent positions, I want both columns to be aligned so that the row line is common for both of them.

If the number of items are not as many as to become 3 rows or more, the design appears to work, but as soon as you have a third row, it becomes different, the rows are not common.

See here, two rows of items:
[image]

The position of the second row is the same for both columns, so the left one adapts to the right one, and that's the way I want it.

But if I add some more items (making 3 rows), this happens:
[image]

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/galivan/pc78n5br/31/).

HTML

```
<div id="ctr">
  <div class="flexctr column1">
     <div class="flexitem" style="height: 36px"></div>
       <div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
         <div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
         <div class="flexitem" style="height: 33px"></div>
         <div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
         <div class="flexitem" style="height: 22px"></div>
         <!-- if you  comment out the below three boxes, the items will line up on each row as we would like: -->
        <div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
         <div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
         <div class="flexitem" style="height: 54px"></div>
         
  </div>
   <div class="flexctr column2">
     
     <div class="flexitem" style="height: 62px"></div>
     <div class="flexitem" style="height: 71px"></div>
     <div class="flexitem" style="height: 49px"></div>
     <div class="flexitem" style="height: 71px"></div>
     <div class="flexitem" style="height: 71px"></div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
<div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
<div class="flexitem" style="height: 46px"></div>
<div id="other"></div>
```

CSS

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#ctr{
  display:flex;
  /* align-items:stretch; */
  flex-direction:row;
  border:2px solid orange;
}
.flexctr{
  display:flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;
   width: 33%;
   border:2px solid black;
}

.flexitem{
  width: 33%; 
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.column1 .flexitem{
   background:purple;
}
.column2 .flexitem{
   background:green;
}
#other{
   height:300px;
   background:lightblue;
}
```

In my own project there is a different effect: if I set the top flex container to "align-items:stretch" (which is default), then there is a gap between the first and second row on the left column (about the height of one item). If I set it to "align-items: baseline", then I get the same effect as in the jsfiddle example. (the jsfiddle example has the default "stretch" value).

Is it possible to achieve the common row positions for the two columns?
If not, is it possible with grid layout?

Comment: That is expected behaviour. There is no way to align elements of different containers in flexbox. Css-Grid has options (subgrid) but that is only supported by Firefix at present

Comment: Grid is the way to go for this project because of the 2 dimensional layout you want